# How can I estimate depth of a feature point / object using single camera?

Tags: computer-vision, monocular

I am trying to estimate depth of a feature point that i find in my image. I read [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7738210/) paper that estimates the depth using a motionless camera and an object of known height to calculate horizon line. I was wondering if its possible to use the same approach for a camera thats moving and object thats stationary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Researchers from Davide Scaramuzza's group authored a paper in 2014 about a probabilistic technique called REMODE that estimates depth from a single moving camera. The algorithm performs per pixel depth estimation from a camera stream and regularization based on uncertainty estimation. It should be suitable for your application involving a moving camera and a stationary object.

The paper can be found [here](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/ICRA14_Pizzoli.pdf), and the implementation of the algorithm can be found [at this repository](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_open_remode). The implementation uses CUDA libraries, so you'd need access to an NVIDIA GPU to run it.